# Prove that a real $2 \times 2$ matrix is orthogonal if and only if it is of one of the following forms: Proof Review And Possible Author Error?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, orthogonal-matrices

> Prove that a real $2 \times 2$ matrix is orthogonal if and only if it is of one of the forms
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b \\
>     -b & a 
>   \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b \\
>     b & -a
>   \end{bmatrix}$
>
> where $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

My understanding is that if and only if represents equivalence. So when we have $A$ if and only if $B$ ($A \Longleftrightarrow B$), this is saying $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$. Therefore, for this problem, we must prove two things:

1. A real $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix has form 
   $\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       -b & a 
     \end{bmatrix}$ or 
   $\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       b & -a
     \end{bmatrix}$.
2. The matrices $\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       -b & a 
     \end{bmatrix}$ and 
   $\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       b & -a
     \end{bmatrix}$
   are orthogonal matrices.

I found 2. to be easy, but I'm still unsure as to whether I did 1. correctly.

**1.**

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
  \end{bmatrix}$ be an orthogonal matrix $\forall a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

$\therefore \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
  \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + c^2 & ab + cd \\
    ab + cd & b^2 + d^2
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$

We now have $a^2 + c^2 = 1, b^2 + d^2 = 1, ab + cd = 0, a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

$\therefore c^2 - b^2 = 0 \implies \pm c = \pm b$ and $a^2 - d^2 = 0 \implies \pm a = \pm d$.

Since we had $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
  \end{bmatrix}$, we have that $b = \pm c$ and $d = \pm a$.

$Q.E.D.$

**2.**

$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    -b & a
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & -b \\
    b & a
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + b^2 & ab - ab \\
    ab - ab & b^2 + a^2
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & -b \\
    b & a
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    -b & a
  \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    b & -a
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    b & -a
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + b^2 & ab - ab \\
    ab - ab & b^2 + a^2
  \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

Since $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

$Q.E.D.$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof for correctness.

**EDIT (New Proof for 1.):**

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
  \end{bmatrix}$ be an orthogonal matrix $\forall a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$

$\therefore \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    b & d
  \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + c^2 & ab + cd \\
    ab + cd & b^2 + d^2
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

$a^2 + c^2 = 1$, $b^2 + d^2 = 1$, $ab + cd = 0$.

Let $a = \cos(\theta)$, $c = \sin(\theta)$, $b = \cos(\phi)$, $d = \sin(\phi)$.

$\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) + \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) = 0$

$\implies cos(\theta - \phi) = 0$

$\therefore \theta - \phi = \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\phi = \theta - \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2}$

$b = \cos\left( \theta - \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right)$ and $d = \sin\left( \theta - \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right)$.

$\therefore b = \cos(\theta)\cos\left( \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right) + \sin(\theta)\sin\left( \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right)$

$= \begin{cases} 
      -\sin(\theta) & \forall \ k \ \text{odd} \\
      \sin(\theta) & \forall \ k \ \text{even} \\
   \end{cases}$

and

$d = \sin(\theta)\cos\left( \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right) - \cos(\theta)\sin\left( \dfrac{(2k + 1)\pi}{2} \right)$

$= \begin{cases} 
      \cos(\theta) & \forall \ k \ \text{odd} \\
      -\cos(\theta) & \forall \ k \ \text{even} \\
   \end{cases}$

$\therefore A = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
    -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
  \end{bmatrix}$ if $k$ is odd

or

$\therefore A = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
    \sin(\theta) & -\cos(\theta)
  \end{bmatrix}$ if $k$ is even

$\therefore A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    -c & a
  \end{bmatrix}$ if $k$ is odd

or

$\therefore A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & c \\
    c & -a
  \end{bmatrix}$ if $k$ is even

$Q.E.D.$

Comment: Seems like you didn't show that you don't have both $d=-a$ and $b=-c$ at the same time in part 1.

Comment: @jgon Thanks for the response. But doesn't the proposition only ask for the forms where we have one of either $d = -a$ or $b = -c$? Note the two matrices shown in the proposition.

Comment: Yes, my point is you seem to have only showed that $b=\pm c$ and $d=\pm a$, but the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & -a \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $b\pm c$ and $d=\pm a$, but is not of either of the forms asked for.

Comment: @jgon Ahh, you're right. Is it possible that the problem author made an error here? I actually think $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & -a \end{pmatrix}$ might be a valid form for the orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @jgon I have posted an edit at the bottom of my main post justifying this.

Comment: You got that $a=0$ or $b=0$, but in that case either $a=-a$ or $b=-b$, so if this is the case, then it still falls into one of the two forms given by the problem author.

Comment: @jgon I figured it out. Thank you for the assistance!